# How do I make a nested var update if it exists in Realm, in Swift?

Tags: database, swift, primary-key, realm, objectmapper

I have an Auth object that has a User object. I store the Auth object because it also has other information (like my access token).

If I log in once, then log out-- no issues. It creates the auth object, which then creates the user object... and logging out deletes the auth object (but keeps the user object) which is fine to me.

However, when I go to log in a second time, it fails because it tries to create the user object again, but the primary key is the same and I get this error:

```
"Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value '123123123'"
```

(123123123 is a sample id)

How do I make it that when I add an Auth object to Realm, it updates the existing user (if exists) instead of trying to create a new one w/ the same primary key?

Thanks!

Auth object:

```
class Auth: Object, Mappable  {
    static var currentAuth: Auth? {
        set {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                if let oldValue = currentAuth {
                    realm.delete(oldValue)
                }
                if let currentAuth = newValue {
                    realm.add(currentAuth)
                }
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("didChangeLogin", object: nil)
        }
        get {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            // there should only be 1 or 0
            return realm.objects(Auth).first
        }
    }

    dynamic var accessToken: String?
    dynamic var user: User?

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        accessToken <- map["access_token"]
        user <- map["user"]
    }

    // MARK: - Convenience
    class func logout() {
        currentAuth = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Required
    required init() { super.init() }
    required init?(_ map: Map) { super.init() }
    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) { super.init(value: value, schema: schema) }
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) { super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema) }
}
```

User object:

```
class User: Base {
    dynamic var username: String?
    dynamic var bio: String?

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map)
        username <- map["username"]
        bio <- map["bio"]
    }

    // MARK: - Requireds
    required init() { super.init() }
    required init?(_ map: Map) { super.init() }
    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) { super.init(value: value, schema: schema) }
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) { super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema) }
}
```

^ For reference

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `User`'s primary key is conflict (Maybe it is defined in `Base` class?).

Realm doesn't have cascading delete, so the `User` object is left even deleting the old `Auth` object.

If you'd like to update when the object that has existing primary key, you should pass `true` to the `update` parameter of `add(_:, update:)` method. However, the `Auth` class doesn't have a primary key property, so you cannot pass `true` to the `update` parameter when adding the `Auth` object.

There are two ways to solve the problem.

1.
The first way is adding a primary key to the `Auth` class (Perhaps, `accessToken` property would be appropriate.). Like the following:

```
class Auth: Object, Mappable  {
    ...
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "accessToken"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, you can pass `true` to the `add(_:, update:)`.

```
if let currentAuth = newValue {
    realm.add(currentAuth, update: true)
}
```

2.

The second way is deleting the old `User` object when deleting old `Auth` object. Like the following:

```
static var currentAuth: Auth? {
    set {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            if let oldUserValue = currentAuth?.user {
                realm.delete(oldUserValue)
            }
            if let oldValue = currentAuth {
                realm.delete(oldValue)
            }
            if let currentAuth = newValue {
                realm.add(currentAuth)
            }
        }
        ...
```